# understanding getRange() coordinates

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's my code.

```
function getFirstEmptyCell(sheet) {
  var column = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  column = sheet.getRange(ct,0)
  return (column);
}
```

the sheet being searched only has data in cell 1, and therefore ct = 1 by the end of the process. I'm trying to understand why it gives me a "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." message.

Comment: sheet.getRange(1,1) is the same as cell A1.  The first number is the row and the second is the column, both starting at 1  If ct = 1, then sheet.getRange(ct,0) is looking for a cell in the first row, but in a column before A which is not valid.  Change the 0 to a 1 for column A.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the numbering started with 0. Thanks!